# CSS: wrap an image around a DIV as an border / frame?

Tags: css, image, html, border, frame

I’ve a DIV named ”content” where I have an image as a border / frame I would like to get around it. I both have one big entire frame (left, right, top, bottom) which matches the width it should be and also I’ve chopped it up so I’ve four single border images (left.png, right.png, etc.).

But I’m having a really hard time trying to attach them to my div so it looks right. What I would like – if possible – is to attach the border (either the single frame image or the four chopped up border images) to be at the side of the div. The div’s width is 800px and I want to leave it at 800px and then attach the borders outside the Div.

Is that possible and if so, how do it do that?
Thank you very much

Sincere
- Mestika

Comment: Please provide your HTML/CSS so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/Pa6kR/24/

This will work no matter what width you put. You have to use 8 images in order to make it work (combine in sprites). Set the corners width and height and background to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what I've tried:

**CSS:**

```
#content{ 
width:800px;
padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left:160px;
margin-right:auto;
overflow:hidden;
background: #e0e0e0 url("../images/frame.png") no-repeat;
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content"> ALL MY CONTENT INSIDE THIS DIV </div>
```